# Using certain plyr functions to calculate more than one thing

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following:

```
           Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width

    1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
    2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
    3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
    4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
    5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
    6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
    7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3
    8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2
    9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2
    10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1
```

Is it possible to calculate more than one thing for the first column, such as min, max and mean using a certain plyr function, and doing that in a single call?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it need to be plyr or would you be happy with a dplyr solution?

Comment: It needs to be plyr :( I'm trying to use ddplyr function but I can't seem to make it work.
I figured I have to use: each(mean,median)(df$column) but when I use it with ddplyr I get an error saying that it has length 2 instead of 1. Which is true because you get 1x2 dataframe when I apply that function. any thoughts?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but would `library("dplyr")

head(iris) %>% 
  summarise(
    max = max(Sepal.Length),
    min = min(Sepal.Length),
    mean = mean(Sepal.Length)
  )` be suitable?